# Can I keep Maven local repository on another machine and use it in my project?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

Where are Maven and pom.xml file kept in a real-time project if the code is at GitHub. I mean can I keep my local repository somewhere in another machine and use it in my project. If yes, how?

Comment: If you are going to use the maven local repo from only one machine then you can share a folder and map it to a drive in windows and change the localRepository tags value to that folder. Ref https://maven.apache.org/settings.html

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam You need to make sure that only one person at a time uses the local repository, which may be hard for a shared folder.

Comment: @JFMeier that why I started my statement with 'If'

Answer (score 2):

Local repositories are not meant for sharing. They are also not "thread-safe" in any way, so accessing them simultaneously from two different builds might break things.

They are populated by the artifacts Maven downloads from MavenCentral and other repositories, and also the stuff you build yourself. As they are more or less a form of cache, there is no need to share them.

If you need a repository that is used from different machines or by different users, set up a Nexus/Artifactory server.